# Why on Mac, NSReadPixel() will cause "_NSReadPixel", referenced from: _main in cctJJibI.o ld: symbol(s) not found?

Tags: cocoa, appkit

On Mac OS X Snow Leopard, the program uses:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

  CGPoint pt;
  pt.x = x;
  pt.y = y;

  NSColor* color = NSReadPixel(pt);
```

but during compilation, it will say:

```
"_NSReadPixel", referenced from:
      _main in cctJJibI.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

the compilation line is

```
gcc -o trytry trytry.m -framework ApplicationServices -framework Foundation
```

gcc's version is `gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is, it needs the AppKit on the compile line as well:

```
gcc -o trytry trytry.m -framework ApplicationServices -framework Foundation 
    -framework AppKit
```

Comment: Yes; the error message is the linker (ld) telling you that it couldn't find that symbol in any library or framework that you told it to use or that it would implicitly use, and the fix is to tell it to use the framework that contains that symbol (in this case, AppKit).